# How to send virtual pageview using vue-analytics?

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics, analytics

My page is rendered using vue, so I use vue-analytics to track it.
Currently, I'm using ajax for my search function, thus, to track the keyword, I need to send a virtual pageview to Google analytics.
I have read through vue-analytics [documents](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-analytics/blob/master/docs/page-tracking.md) and try things like this:

```
this.$ga.page('/', 'q=keyword')
```

but no luck so far.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

try passing the explicit parameter object like:

```
this.$ga.page({
  page: '/',
  title: 'Home page',
  location: window.location.href
})
```

set the value for `page` as you wish to see it in reports

Comment: Not work when i add the param to `location`. I enabled site search tracking.

Comment: this would probably be a case if your `location` value contains a hash before param. Analytics used to strip part of the URL following a hash. Try another way to compose a value for `location` so the param precedes a hash sign.

Comment: I tried to send location by a string with no hash, but it still didnot catch the params @Дмитро Булах

Comment: try skipping the `page` parameter and only pass `location` and `title`. Keep in mind that query param might be stripped from the reported page path